# Databricks error while trying to create delta table on ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working with Azure Databricks to create a delta table on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and running into error.

***Code:***

```
dataframe.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("path","abfss://<ContainerName>@<StorageAccount>.dfs.core.windows.net").saveAsTable("test_table")
```

***Error:***

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: abfss://<ContainerName>@<StorageAccount>.dfs.core.windows.net_delta_log
```

Comment: do you really have path as `abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net` or it was just changed to hide names?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, It was a typo. I have updated my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set path to the specific directory inside your Data Lake, not onto the top of the container. Something like:

```py
ContainerName = "container"
StorageAccount = "account"
table_path = f"abfss://{ContainerName}@{StorageAccount}.dfs.core.windows.net/test-table"
dataframe.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite")\
  .option("path", table_path).saveAsTable("test_table")
```

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I am running into this below error Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling saveAsTable Failure to initialize configuration.

Comment: As I said, try to specify directory name

Comment: don't we need to provide SAS token?

Comment: there are different authentication methods, but yes - you need to have correct configuration